# Reminder Encounter upon testing the project

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

I am following this [LINK](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php) for viewing a MS Word using `vb.net`. I don't know what causes this to prompt. Everytime I close the windows it prompts. Anyone knows about this?.

And I am having an error to this one

```
If Dialog1.ShowDialog() Then
 If Dialog1.GetChooseType() = 1 Then
    AxEDOffice1.CreateNew("Word.Application")
 ElseIf Dialog1.GetChooseType() = 2 Then
    AxEDOffice1.CreateNew("Excel.Application")
 ElseIf Dialog1.GetChooseType() = 3 Then
    AxEDOffice1.CreateNew("PowerPoint.Application")
 ElseIf Dialog1.GetChooseType() = 4 Then
     AxEDOffice1.CreateNew("Visio.Application")
 ElseIf Dialog1.GetChooseType() = 5 Then
    AxEDOffice1.CreateNew("MSProject.Application")
End If
```

End If

He didn't posted a step on how to do this one.
[image]

Comment: Down Voted + Leave.. Didn't leave a commend why..

Comment: I get the feeling you've got to buy the product from Edraw for that message to be removed. I guess you hit the **Try It Free** button?

Comment: @Jinx88909 I just follow the instruction from the link

Comment: I think you may need to contact Edraw and speak with them. It does look like you're using the free version and with that comes this annoying popup. Vendors like to do things like this in an attempt to make people buy the product.

Comment: @Jinx88909 I don't have that money to but the product

Comment: There are other ways to integrate into Office products but it has been a while. Maybe do a bit of research and see if there is another solution that fits.

Comment: @Jinx88909 I try to look for older version but no luck can't find. Is there any other way to do this w/o using the edraw?

Comment: There's a lot out there. What's good and what's not I'm unsure have a look at [this](https://netoffice.codeplex.com) which may prove useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128790/discussion-between-kira-and-jinx88909).